# cannot insert data in codeforst

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

this code is not giving any error but the data is not inserting in database except hospitals data

public  class HospitalInitializer  : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

```
{
    protected override void Seed(DoctorContext context)
    {

        var hospitals = new List<Hospital> 
       {
            new Hospital() {Name = "Agha Khan"}, 
            new Hospital() {Name = "liaquat national"}, 
           new Hospital() {Name = "Tabba heart center"} 
       };

        hospitals.ForEach(c => context.Hospitals.Add(c));

        context.SaveChanges();
        var Doctors = new List<Doctor> 
       {
            new Doctor() {Name = "dr shah", qualification="MBBS", fee= 1000, specialization= "General", Hospital = context.Hospitals.Single(p=>p.Name == "Agha Khan"),
                appointments = new List<appointment>{ 
                                             new appointment { date_appoint=  "2013-11-20 "  ,
                                                            confirm_appoint= "yes",
                                                            cancelation_appoint=" Not yet",
                                             }}
            },
            new Doctor() {Name = "dr ahmed", qualification="MBBS", fee= 1500, specialization= "Derm", Hospital = context.Hospitals.Single(p=>p.Name == "liaquat national"),
           appointments = new List<appointment>{ 
                                             new appointment { date_appoint= "2013-11-20 " ,
                                                              confirm_appoint= "yes",
                                                              cancelation_appoint=" Not yet",
                                             }}
            },
            new  Doctor() {Name = "dr Faisal", qualification="MBBS MRCOG", fee= 1500, specialization= "Derma", Hospital=context.Hospitals.Single(p=>p.Name == "baqai national")  ,
      appointments = new List<appointment>{ 
                                             new appointment { date_appoint="2013-11-20 " ,
                                                              confirm_appoint= "yes",
                                                              cancelation_appoint=" Not yet",
                                             }}
            }

       };

        Doctors.ForEach(c => context.Doctors.Add(c));

        context.SaveChanges();
        var facilities = new List<Facility>
        {
            new Facility() { facilityname = "ECG", fac_type = "CARDIC", Doctors=context.Doctors.Find(1)},
              new Facility() { facilityname = "eco", fac_type = "heart", Doctors=context.Doctors.Find(2)},
           new Facility() { facilityname = "eco", fac_type = "heart", Doctors=context.Doctors.Find(3)}
```

};
            facilities.ForEach(c => context.Facilities.Add(c));

```
        context.SaveChanges();



        var patients = new List<patient>
                                         {
                              new patient() { name = "abbass" , type_disease= "brain disorder", pat_history= "2 years", cell_no = 03457889654, phonenumber= 35660453 , Doctors=context.Doctors.Find(1)},

                              new patient() {name= "amna qasim" ,type_disease =" skin allergy" ,pat_history= "2 years",
                              cell_no = 03457889654, phonenumber= 35660453 , Doctors=context.Doctors.Find(2)},

                              new patient() {name= "tooba ahmed" ,type_disease ="heart problem" ,pat_history= "1 years",
                              cell_no = 03457889654, phonenumber= 35660453 , Doctors=context.Doctors.Find(3)},
        };
        patients.ForEach(c => context.patients.Add(c));

        context.SaveChanges();




        var newsletter = new List<Newsletter>
        {
            new Newsletter () { url="www.news1.com",
                                description="newsletter of janvary",
                                UserProfiles= context.UserProfiles.Find(1)
            },
              new Newsletter () { url="www.newsletter2.com",
                                description="newsletter of feb",
                                UserProfiles= context.UserProfiles.Find(2)
            },
              new Newsletter () { url="www.news1.com",
                                description="newsletter of march",
                                UserProfiles= context.UserProfiles.Find(3)
            }
        };

        newsletter.ForEach(c => context.newsletters.Add(c));

        context.SaveChanges();


        var roles = new List<Role>
  {
  new Role() { 
           roletype="doctor",  
            roledescription =" skin specialits", 

             UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>{ 
                                             new UserProfile { username= "shah1",
                                                            email="shah.ali@gmail.com",
                                                            password="ali12",
                                                            phonenumber= 033345678,
                                                            city= "karachi",
                                                            country= "pakistan",
                                                            postalcode= 34567,
                                                            address= "gulshan e iqbal town",
                                             }
             }
  },
   new Role() { 
           roletype="doctor",  
            roledescription =" skin specialits", 

             UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>{ 
                                             new UserProfile { username= "shah1",
                                                            email="shah.ali@gmail.com",
                                                            password="ali12",
                                                            phonenumber= 033345678,
                                                            city= "karachi",
                                                            country= "pakistan",
                                                            postalcode= 34567,
                                                            address= "gulshan e iqbal town",
                                             }
             }
  },
   new Role() { 
           roletype="patient",  
            roledescription =" patient of skin diseases", 

             UserProfiles = new List<UserProfile>{ 
                                             new UserProfile { username= "gm1",
                                                            email="tayaba@gmail.com",
                                                            password="ali12",
                                                            phonenumber= 0334567892,
                                                            city= "karachi",
                                                            country= "pakistan",
                                                            postalcode= 34567,
                                                            address= "f.b area",
                                             }
             }
  }
  };
        roles.ForEach(c => context.Roles.Add(c));

        context.SaveChanges();


        var ambulance = new List<Ambulance>
         {
         new Ambulance()
         {
           amb_no = "2367",
          //Doctors  = context.Doctors.Find(1),
          Locations = new List<Location>{ 
                                             new Location { location= "gulshan e iqbal",
                                              Facilities= context.Facilities.Find(1)
                                             }

         }},
           new Ambulance()
          {
           amb_no =" 12457",
          //Doctors  = context.Doctors.Find(1),
          Locations = new List<Location>{ 
                                             new Location { location= "defence",
                                              Facilities= context.Facilities.Find(2)
                                             }
         }
          },
            new Ambulance()
          {
           amb_no = "56787",
          //Doctors  = context.Doctors.Find(1),
          Locations = new List<Location>{ 
                                             new Location { location= "aisha manzil",
                                              Facilities= context.Facilities.Find(3)
                                             }
         }
          },
         };

        ambulance.ForEach(c => context.Ambulances.Add(c));

        context.SaveChanges();








    }

}
```

}

please help me to find why this code is not inserting into database

Comment: It looks like you should get exceptions that you probably catch silently .